# Real part of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, reference-request

Let $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a polynomial with complex roots $\{\alpha _j +i\beta _j\}_{j}.$
**Question:** is there a name for $q(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that the roots of $q$ are the set of roots $\{\alpha _j\}_j$? I guess, one can deform the roots with a parameter $t$ by considering polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x,t]$ and considering roots $\alpha _j +i\cdot (1-t)\beta _j$ but I am curious if there is any literature or known results around this idea. I have seen deformation of polynomials via homotopies to the derivarite see [this](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00653770/document), but the change seems smoother because is like taking out multiplicities.

**Context:** I am interested in a family of polynomials with complex roots in which the real part of those roots seems to interlace.